# Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
    square = (x) -> x * x
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]        
    squares = (square num for num in list)
</script>
```

The CoffeeScript compiler is written in JavaScript, so can I send it to the client to compile/run this code in the client's browser?

Comment: It says on the front page of the CoffeeScript website: "The CoffeeScript compiler is itself written in CoffeeScript, using the Jison parser generator. The command-line version of coffee is available as a Node.js utility. The core compiler however, does not depend on Node, and can be run in any JavaScript environment, or in the browser (see "Try CoffeeScript", above). "

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it does, but it doesn't seem to be recommended as it says nothing about how to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [this](https://coffeescript.org/#scripts)?

> ### `"text/coffeescript"` Script Tags
>
> While it’s not recommended for serious use, CoffeeScripts may be
> included directly within the browser using `<script type="text/coffeescript">` tags. The source includes a compressed and
> minified version of the compiler ([Download current version here, 77k
> when gzipped](https://coffeescript.org/v2/browser-compiler-legacy/coffeescript.js)) as
> `docs/v2/browser-compiler-legacy/coffeescript.js`. Include this file
> on a page with inline CoffeeScript tags, and it will compile and
> evaluate them in order.
>
> The usual caveats about CoffeeScript apply — your inline scripts will
> run within a closure wrapper, so if you want to expose global
> variables or functions, attach them to the `window` object.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://coffeescript.org/v2/browser-compiler-legacy/coffeescript.js"></script>

<script type="text/coffeescript">
square = (x) -> x * x
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]        
squares = (square num for num in list)

console.log squares
</script>
```

Answer (score 50):

Jeremy already has this one, but let me add some important details and caveats:

1. At 39k gzipped (compare to jQuery at 29k), `coffee-script.js` is a big file; so unless you're actually letting your users run their own CoffeeScript, you really shouldn't use it in production.
2. As mentioned in the documentation, each CoffeeScript snippet will be in its own anonymous closure. So your example snippet wouldn't do anything—`squares` wouldn't be visible outside of the script. Instead, you'd want to change it to `window.squares = ...`.
3. All CoffeeScript code, whether external or inline, will run *after* all JavaScript code on the page. That's because `coffee-script.js` doesn't read your `<script type="text/coffeescript>` tags until after the document is ready, by which time your JavaScripts have already run.
4. Remote CoffeeScripts are loaded via `XMLHTTPRequest`, which means that they must be hosted on the same domain as your site. (Certain browsers—Chrome, at least—also have a problem with doing `XMLHTTPRequest`s on `file://` paths.)
5. Currently, the order in which different remote CoffeeScripts run is not guaranteed. I submitted a patch for this, but it's not officially a part of CoffeeScript yet. See [this pull request](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/1058).

So, you might want to look at some alternatives for serving CoffeeScript as compiled JavaScript instead. If you're developing for a Ruby or Python server, there are plugins available. I've tried to list them all at http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Web-framework-plugins.

If you're developing a site without a backend, a tool I highly recommend looking at is [Middleman](https://github.com/middleman/middleman), which lets you work with CoffeeScript (as well as Haml and Sass, if you want) during development, then compile and minify it for production deployment.

Comment: One might argue that if you're writing a lot of CoffeeScript, the smaller code size will make up for the larger library size.

Comment: @Soviut Ah, but there's no library for directly minifying CoffeeScript. (Nor should there be!) I can pretty much guarantee that your minified JS will be smaller than your CoffeeScript source.

Comment: Another caveat is that you don't control what versions of JavaScript the browsers are or aren't supporting. It's not like Node where if deprecated methods CS is relying on drop off you can just stick with an older version. This might not matter for years to come and bite somebody not you. It might matter tomorrow. If CS still relies on some of the deprecated arguments stuff, then it could matter soon because the browser vendors have performance incentive to let go of that stuff.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but rumor has it [this pull request](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/pull/1277) fixed #5.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is yes. I won't repeat @Trevor's excellent answer, but rather just provide an example of what you're thinking about:

http://forgivingworm.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/running-coffeescript-in-browser/

Basically you

1. Tag your coffeescript with the **text/coffeescript**
2. Include coffee-script.js after all coffeescript on the page (the
   compiler will evaluate and compile all coffeescript in order)

Sample HTML below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>In-Browser test</title>
    <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js&#8221;> </script>
    <script type=”text/coffeescript”>
      $ -> $(‘#header‘).css ‘background-color‘, ‘green‘
    </script>
    <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js&#8221;> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id=”header” style=”color:white”>CoffeeScript is alive!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now GitHub disabled directly get js files from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>CoffeScript on browser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/coffeescript">
      alert 'It works!'
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.7.1/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- CoffeeScript has to be loaded after the script you want to run.
- if using `src` you must be able to access the file via `XMLHTTPRequest`, in particular it fails on browsers with `file://`.