# Get started with Backbone and CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, backbone.js

I think this is more of a [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) question.  I want to be able to use classes from [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) in a `foo.coffee` file.  I tried using the `-r` option to require [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) when running the `coffee` command:

```
coffee -r "../backbone" -c foo.coffee
```

The compiler complained that [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) was undefined.  I'm sure that this must be pretty simple.  It's easy to find examples of people using [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) together. I also tried requiring the class at the top of the file like so:

```
Backbone.model = require('../../backbone').Model

class foo extends Backbone.model
```

I could write it to `console.log` in the `initialize` method.  When I tried writing `this` to `console.log`, I just got an empty object `{}`.

Can anyone tell me how to get this going?

Answer (score 13):

If you're using [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), I recommend checking out [Brunch](http://brunchwithcoffee.com).
It may just get you past your difficulties.

Answer (score 10):

Could you provide more of your code? I wasn't able to replicate the issue you had with `initialize`. Here's my code, with `backbone.js` in the same directory as the `coffee` file:

```
Backbone = require './backbone'

class foo extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: ->
    console.log this

new foo
```

On `new foo`, `initialize` is called and the output is

```
{ attributes: {},
  _escapedAttributes: {},
  cid: 'c0',
  _previousAttributes: {} }
```

As to the issue with `-r`, there are two reasons it doesn't work: First, `-r` performs

```
require '../backbone'
```

without assigning it to anything. Since Backbone doesn't create globals (only exports), the module has to be assigned when it's `require`d.

Second, using `-r` in conjunction with `-c` doesn't add the `require`d library to the compiled output. Instead, it requires it *during* compilation. Really, `-r` only exists so that you can extend the compiler itself—for instance, adding a preprocessor or postprocessor to the compilation pipeline—as [documented on the wiki](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BExtensibility%5D-Hooking-into-the-Command-Line-Compiler).

Comment: Thanks for the help. All I was trying to do was do the Backbone todos tutorial in Coffeescript.  I cloned the backbone repo, and then created my own directory under examples for coffee. Long story short, I moved backbone and underscore into the same directory and the "foo" example above worked.  I was also able to get to "hello world" for the tut. I just commented out the require statement and the backbone variable declaration in the generated code. Then, I loaded up index.html with expected console output.  Is there an easier workflow when my html loads libs that coffee needs to compile?

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled :) (See my answer to that question for more alternatives for compiling for the browser. `coffee` is versatile, but it's definitely not the right tool for every job.)

Comment: Ok. Fair enough.  At the moment, I'm trying to require the 'backbone-localstorage' file that is part of Todos.  It expects underscore to be loaded.  Without trying to define and compile Todos in the browser ... how do I manage these kind of dependencies so that I can compile?  I tried requiring underscore and assigning it to _ in my Todos.coffee. I still got "_ is not defined".  Surely I'm missing something obvious???