# CoffeeScript testing and deployment on PHP / LAMP stack

Tags: php, javascript, lamp, coffeescript

I'm interested in dabbling in [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), but I'd rather not have to recompile down to Javascript by hand every time I want to test. Is there an easy way dynamically convert CoffeeScript to vanilla Javascript while working on a LAMP stack, either on the server side or the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Server side

Check out [kohana-coffeescript](https://github.com/DanHulton/kohana-coffeescript), which makes it easy to serve CoffeeScript from PHP's Kohana framework.

### Client side

See [Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled) Fantastic for testing.

Comment: No problem. And may I mention that I've written [a book on CoffeeScript](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript) that you may want to check out? </plug>