# simple coffeescript web page

Tags: coffeescript

I have seen coffescript tutorials that show how to use coffeescript with rails, nodejs, or even coffeescript REPL for learning it.

How can I create a web project where I can just write a cofeescript script inside an HTML page, I mean something like

```
<script type ="text/coffeescript">
//some coffeescript code
</script>
```

[How to use coffeescript in developing web-sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117190/how-to-use-coffeescript-in-developing-web-sites) just tells to include output javascript and test it. But, I do not want to do that (I feel its just clumsy).

I also saw coffeescript web site, it has small amount of direction regarding this, it says-

[image]

I tried it, I included a those scripts along with jquery. But my page is remains blank. Has anyone does it before, can you  provide a sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code that didn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just include `coffee-script.js` in the usual manner and then add `<script>` elements like this:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
    alert 'pancakes!'
</script>​
```

or this

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
    eggs = 'gotta have some'
    document.write "It really is CoffeeScript: #{eggs}"
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DmuHh/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iluyoz more explicitely illustrates the same thing. ( http://jsfiddle.net/ is a nice tool also, but hides libs behind checkboxes )

Comment: @MarkHu: The [editable version](http://jsbin.com/iluyoz/1/edit) would be even more explicit :)