# How do I transpile coffeescript with Adobe Brackets

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, adobe-brackets

I know something like this shouldn't stump me, but it has.

I am learning how to use coffeescript and using Adobe Brackets as my text editor. So how do I use coffeescript in Adobe Brackets?

Let's say I have an index.html and a script.coffeescript. How should I be including script in index? Is it `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`, anticipating it to be compiled? And how do I set script.coffeescript to be compiled in Brackets? I have seen an example using Cake, but I'm not entirely sure how it fits into the project structure.

Comment: Yes, coffeescript expects to be compiled to javascript before you can include it in your page like a normal script. Check out http://coffeescript.org/#usage

Comment: You don't _have_ to transpile it first, but probably should. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117190/how-to-use-coffeescript-in-developing-web-sites; I think you should change the question to "How do I transpile coffeescript with Adobe Brackets".

Answer (score -1):

Open Brackets. In the bottom right hand corner is a box three from the right, (in mine) and open it, (it will say something like HTML or CSS or Javascript or Bash.

If you open it and scroll to the c's, It should have a CoffeeScript option.

Is this what you were looking for?