# Can I use Coffeescript in client side too?

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any way to use CoffeeScript in client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled)

Comment: Use what you want for hobby projects but from a production/maintainability perspective, it's a terrible idea. You don't have to upgrade your version of Node.js if CS falls behind some deprecation finally getting dropped from the language. But you don't control the browsers you have to support. That leaves you at the mercy of how fast the CS team responds and totally screwed if there no longer is a CS team.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript \*there\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Compile the CoffeeScript to JavaScript and deploy it as you would any JavaScript file, or
2. Use [`coffee-script.js`](https://coffeescript.org/#scripts), which allows you to put `<script type="text/coffeescript>` tags in your page.

The latter isn't recommended for production use, but it's nice for development. Or for usage in online editors like these:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://coffeescript.org/v2/browser-compiler-legacy/coffeescript.js"></script>

<script type="text/coffeescript">
console.log 'Hello World!'
</script>
```

See the related question: [Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled)

Answer (score 1):

See also Webmake plugin for CoffeeScript -> [https://github.com/medikoo/webmake-coffee](https://github.com/medikoo/webmake-coffee#webmake-coffee)

It allows you to organize coffee modules in Node.js style and bundle it for browser. It provides source maps support, so you can debug CoffeeScript files as they are, directly in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

To not compile everytime you can use -w param and coffee will compile the file everytime file change

```
coffee -wco src/ public/js
```

Comment: the question is for compiling on client side ie in the browser. Your answer is for server compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done by adding a CoffeeScript `src` tag to the head section of your html page.

Download the CoffeeScript source from this path: http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js

Copy and paste the below code and try to run in a browser:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printHelloJava(){
alert("Hello Javascript");
}
</script>
<script src="coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
@printHello = ->
  alert "Hello Coffee Script"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Coffee Script on client side</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="printHelloJava();" value="Hello Java">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="printHello()" value="Hello Coffee">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CDN coffeescript for better and faster performance.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.7.1/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/1.11.1/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

Then use `type="text/coffeescript"` for compile `Coffee Script`.

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
    // add code here
</script>
```