# coffeescript to js service

Tags: web-services, coffeescript

Is there a service available to compile `.coffee` files and serve them as plain JS files :

```
<script src="http://coffee2js.com?url=http://gist.github.com/foo.coffee"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything like that. You can try this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798884/can-i-use-coffeescript-in-client-side-too

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use `text/coffeescript` tags with CoffeeScript and have the browser compile it in realtime. See [here](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts). Do **NOT USE** on production.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [CoffeeMaker](https://github.com/ironboy/CoffeeMaker). Just install it on any server with a LAMP stack, and deploy your CoffeeScript files there.

Answer (score 1):

I created [Coffee2JS](https://mikethedj4.github.io/Coffee2JS/) which is just a simple converter.

You can paste your code in 1 textarea and it'll show in the other by either a keyup event or by clicking a convert button.

There's also an option to download your converted CoffeeScript as a .js file.

Comment: my pleasure treasure

Answer (score 0):

[js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org) is good site that I use. It works very well. Just paste in JS and outputs coffee then just rename file and paste in the coffee.