# Is it possible to compile Coffeescript code in script tags in html files?

Tags: html, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to send CoffeeScript to the client's browser and have it compiled to JavaScript *there*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled)

Is there a simple way to compile Coffeescript that is inside `<script>` tags inside html, or do you usually have all Coffeescript in separate files?

Comment: Andrew already nailed it. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled

Comment: I was more thinking of compiling inline Coffeescript to Javascript on the server.  Basically running the Coffeescript compiler as a preprocessor and ignoring the HTML.

Comment: Any specific reason why you cannot put it in a separate file? That way you can work with the existing toolchain. Otherwise you'd have to roll something like @Trevor mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Responding to dvcolgan's clarifying comment:

So, you want to have an HTML file on the server with inline CoffeeScript that gets served as HTML with inline JavaScript. The CoffeeScript compiler doesn't support this directly, but you could write a Node script to do it fairly easily, using the `coffee-script` library and [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to do the HTML parsing.

Exactly how you want to implement this would depend on the web framework you're using. You probably don't want the CoffeeScript compiler to run on every request (it's pretty fast, but it's still going to reduce the number of requests/second your server can handle); instead, you'd want to compile your HTML once and then serve the compiled version from a cache. Again, I don't know of any existing tools that do this, but it shouldn't be too hard to write your own.

Answer (score 15):

Indeed there is. There's a post about it [here](http://forgivingworm.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/running-coffeescript-in-browser/).

The summary of that article is this:

1. Include in your HTML document your script with type `text/coffeescript`
2. Include in the head of the page this line:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/master/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js"></script>
   ```

Beware that doing this isn't encouraged.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>In-Browser test</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/master/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/coffeescript">
    $ -> $('#header').css 'background-color', 'green'
  </script>
  <h1 style="color:white" id="header">CoffeeScript is alive!</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: snippet fails in Chrome with: Refused to execute script from 'http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.