# Calling coffeescript defined function from <script> in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a rails app and I am rewriting all my JS in CoffeeScript just to check it out.

I understand CoffeeScript compiles to JS but I am having trouble with something.

I am using Google Maps API and I have a script tag in one of my html.erb files as follows:

```
<script>
initialize()
</script>
```

Now my initialize used to work because it was just written in javascript, but now that I have a coffeescript function instead the browser console says:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined"
```

I put this at the bottom of the coffeescript file after the function definition, but still no dice.

```
window["initialize"] = initialize
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to compile Coffeescript code in script tags in html files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860942/is-it-possible-to-compile-coffeescript-code-in-script-tags-in-html-files)

Comment: If you rewrote the javascript in Coffeescript correctly, so it yields the same original code, it should work. If it doesn't, you did something wrong... the compiled javascript output is not as expected.

Comment: I used an online converter, I guess there was an error introduced. Thanks for the warning. Do you have to restart the Rails server after writing CoffeeScript in order for the compiler to create the javascript? Just curious if you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This really does not have anything to do with CoffeeScript vs JS. But is rather due to the fact that your inline script is run before the external file which declares `window.initialize` is run.

Its widely accepted that inline script tags are a bad practice. So start out by getting rid of it.

This is an example of how you can use the [google loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) & [jQuery.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) instead of a global callback function:

```
jQuery(function(){
  var apiLoaded = jQuery.Deferred();
  var mapInit = jQuery.Deferred();
  var $map_canvas = $('#map_canvas');

  if ( $map_canvas.length ) {
    google.load("maps", "3", { other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){
      apiLoaded.resolve(google);
    }});

    apiLoaded.done(function(g){
      var map = new g.maps.Map($map_canvas[0],{
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(63.399313, 13.082236),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      mapInit.resolve(map);
    });

    mapInit.done(function(map){
      // do something with the map!
    });
  }
});
```

In case you are not using jQuery or the loader you need to use polling to check if the google maps API is loaded:

```
function init(gmaps){
    // do something with the maps api...
}

function isLoaded(){
  if (!window.google){
    window.setTimeout(function(){ isLoaded() }, 10);
  } else {
     init(window.google.maps);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll leave translating this into Coffeescript to you. And be a good boy and put it in an external file.

Comment: Added example of using polling instead of promises