# Why does coffeescript angular demo fail in jsfiddle when an identical javascript one works?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I was building a jsfiddle angular app in coffeescript. It failed, and I reduced the failure to this minimal one:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        {{text}}
    </div>
</body>
```

This javascript fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/nje7H/

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "Hello."
});
```

However, this coffeescript fiddle fails: http://jsfiddle.net/nje7H/1/

```
app = angular.module "MyApp", []

app.controller "MyController", ($scope) ->
    $scope.text = "Hello."
```

The console shows "Uncaught Error: No module: MyApp"

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsfiddle uses `<script type="text/coffeescript">` elements and a library to compile the coffeescript on the client, which doesn't occur until the dom is ready and the code doesn't execute until after angular bootstraps. It will work if you manually bootstrap angular in your code ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/tX3LW/1/)):

```
angular.bootstrap document.body, ['MyApp']
```

In a production environment you should be compiling your coffeescript into javascript for the browser and there wouldn't be a problem.  See [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled).

Comment: AFAIK, jsfiddle.net uses `<script type="text/coffeescript">` and client-side compilation of the CoffeeScript. That would support your conjecture, a quick *View Source* in the CoffeeScript fiddle would clear things up.