# Phonegap with ruby files

Tags: cordova

I try to develop app with phonegap. I have this file "welcome.html.erb". when I run the app the message I get

> Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted

when I remove the 'erg' to "Welcome.html" it's work but the css and js don't load, I search an answer for this question and i Found that I need to add "
" to the file config.xml, still doesn't work.

How should i work with phonegap and ruby together?

Thanks!

Comment: where is the welcome.html.erb located? Is it on a websever or inside the phonegap App? Can you show us your welcome.html file? does the welcome.html.erb work on a normal desktop browser?

Comment: i load the welcome.html.erb from the app. I added to the www folder.

Comment: Your statement is not clear. I assuming that the file welcome.html is there in the app. If that is the case it would not work. Ruby is server side scripting language it needs to be run on a webserver. The webserver will interpret the welcome.html.erb file and send an html/css/javascript file to the app for rendering. Your phonegap/cordova app is just like a web browser that runs (html/javascript/css) in the form of a app. The advantage that you get from cordova is that you can access native ( contacts, camera etc) features of the phone. Hope you have  understood what I am trying to say.

Comment: Can i run file.coffe? the file is in my project

Comment: http://imgur.com/JYdC2ao

Comment: I did not understand? what is the link about? did not see anything.

Comment: how can i run coffescript file?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled)